# need help on update syntax error in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert, unique-index

I have a table called m0_curve and is in a SQLite database.
In this table i have only 4 parameters in the table all real :
ctrl,flow,power,pressure

when I execute this query :

> SELECT CASE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 'm0_curve' WHERE ctrl = '0' AND pressure = '117.21') WHEN 0 THEN ( UPDATE 'm0_curve' SET flow = '0' , power = '0' WHERE ctrl = '0' AND pressure = '117.21' ) ELSE INSERT INTO 'm0_curve' (ctrl,flow,power,pressure) VALUES( '0' , '0' , '0' , '117.21' ) END;

It gives me a syntax error :
"Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "UPDATE": syntax error"
Looking through the sqlite manual I dont understand why?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: This type of query is not supported by SQLite.

Comment: perhaps upsert? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: I have an upsert for another command but can you make upserts when the values are not unique? I need to check uniqueness of both these values

Comment: If you want the combination of ctrl and pressure to be unique then add a unique index on it and use UPSERT.

Comment: It crossed my mind to do that but thats a way round a proper syntax

Comment: I guess can always do an `insert ... where not exists(...)`  followed by an `update ... where ...` I don't believe you can say sql server has proper syntax and sqlite doesn't, they are just different. If these were in a transaction they would be effectively an upsert (in a general or loose sense of the term). Actually I'm not sure if any rdbms allows you to put a sql updates and insert statement inside case expressions - hmmm ? I guess I will have to try!

Comment: This is not *proper syntax* for SQLite. UPSERT is the proper way to do this.

Comment: This doesnt work in an upsert unless the values are unique

Comment: That is correct. I was just reviewing the documentation so: *UPSERT is a special syntax addition to INSERT that causes the INSERT to behave as an UPDATE or a no-op if the INSERT would violate a uniqueness constraint. UPSERT is not standard SQL. UPSERT in SQLite follows the syntax established by PostgreSQL. UPSERT syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04).* Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: Do you want the combination of ctrl and pressure to be unique?

Comment: So, perhaps some background is needed. For each new pressure in combination with a new ctrl I want to insert the value. If I allready have that combination I want to update it. And in the future I would like to update It using the mean value of all previous entrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each new pressure in combination with a new ctrl I want to insert
> the value. If I already have that combination I want to update it

This means that you want the combination of `ctrl` and `pressure` to be unique and you can implement this with a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_ctrl_pressure ON m0_curve(ctrl, pressure);
```

Then use [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) to insert new rows:

```
INSERT INTO m0_curve (ctrl, flow, power, pressure) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', '117.21')
ON CONFLICT(ctrl, pressure) DO UPDATE 
SET flow = EXCLUDED.flow, 
    power = EXCLUDED.power;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fa934e71f87bd1e442694e77acbd0473).